# How to make a, "setWelcome" command using database(MongoDB) and Discord.js?

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I want to make a command for my bot that'll enable people to make a custom welcome message for their guild. So far, I'm able to get the information into the database, but I don't know how to tell my bot to fetch the data and send the message in a specific channel for a specific guild.

This is the code for when a member joins the guild

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd, message', async (member, message) => {
  if (member.bot) {
    return
  } else {

  const welcome = require('./models/welcSchema');

  const welcSchema = await welcome.findOne({
    GuildID: message.guild.id
  })

  if (welcSchema) {
    const mssg = welcSchema.Message;
    const chan = welcSchema.ChannelID;
  member.guild.channels.resolve(chan).send(mssg);
  }
}
});
```

and here's the welcSchema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const welcSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

GuildID: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
Message: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
ChannelID: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model(`welcomes`, welcSchema);
```

I don't get any errors, the bot just doesn't send anything when a member joins.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out, I removed the message thing at the top of the code and where it says, "message.guild.id" and changed it to, "member.guild.id".